# taking out two random balls from a basket

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are a white balls, b black balls and c brown balls.
we are pulling out a random 2 and not returning them.

What is the probability that :

a) The two random balls are from different colors ?

b) It is known that the two balls that were taken out were the same color, what is the probability that both of them were white ?

I am not sure how i should calculate it, stuck at the beggining.

Comment: Would you be able to answer the question if the number of balls for each color were actually given?

Comment: Having trouble in that as well,,. i'll choose one out of the combined sum for the first part, for the second part i should pick another one but i am not sure from what i should choose it

Comment: Easier, I expect, to work from the compliment.  What is the probability that both are white?  both black?  both brown?  The answer to a. is one minus the sum of these.

Comment: Let's assume you have $4$ whites, $5$ blacks and $6$ browns Total there are 15 balls. First ball white: $4/15$ second ball white $3/14$ Both white: Multiply probabilities. Same for blacks and browns. Add these probabilities and subtract from $1$ (Complement rule).

Comment: If $n=a+b+c$ then the probability is $\frac{ab+bc+ca}{\binom{n}{2}}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a) P(two random ball are of different colors) = 1 - P(two random balls are of the same color) as these two are complementary events and they span the whole set of possibilities.

P(two random balls are of the same color) = P(two random balls are white) + P(two random balls are black) + P(two random balls are brown)

Moreover, the probability that two random balls are white is equal to the chance that the first ball is white and the second ball is also white given that the first ball is white. Here, we would apply the bayes rule, i.e.

P(first and second balls are white) = P(first ball is white)$\times$P(second ball is white given that the first ball is white)

Here, P(first ball is white) is simply the chance of picking a white ball out of $a$ white balls and $a+b+c$ total balls, which is equal to
$$
\frac{a}{a+b+c}
$$
Now, conditional on picking the first ball as white, we have $a-1$ white balls left in a bowl of a total of $a+b+c-1$ balls. Hence P(second ball is white given that the first ball is white) would be equal to
$$
\frac{a-1}{a+b+c-1}
$$
Therefore, the probability of picking two white balls is equal to 
$$
\frac{a}{a+b+c}\frac{a-1}{a+b+c-1}
$$

For two black balls, similar calculations would yield
$$
\frac{b}{a+b+c}\frac{b-1}{a+b+c-1}
$$
and for two brown balls, we would have
$$
\frac{c}{a+b+c}\frac{c-1}{a+b+c-1}.
$$
Thus the total probability of picking two same colors in a row is 
$$
\frac{a(a-1)+b(b-1)+c(c-1)}{(a+b+c)(a+b+c-1)}
$$
and probability of picking different colors would be 1 minus the above probability.

b) For this part, the idea would be normalizing the chances of getting two white balls, where the normalization is due to restricting our attention to a subset of the outcomes, i.e. when we pick balls with the same color.

This would be equal to P(picking two white balls)/P(picking two balls of the same color)

We have already calculated these probabilities above, and this would correspond to
$$
\frac{\frac{a(a-1)}{(a+b+c)(a+b+c-1)}}{\frac{a(a-1)+b(b-1)+c(c-1)}{(a+b+c)(a+b+c-1)}}
= \frac{{a}({a-1})}{{a(a-1)+b(b-1)+c(c-1)}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Well the probability that you get two white balls, $p_1$, is
$$p_1=\frac {\binom{a}{2}}{\binom {a+b+c}{2}}$$
Since the numerator gives the number of ways you can choose two white balls from the set of white balls, and the denominator gives the number of ways you can pick 2 balls from the whole set. Therefore assuming all outcomes are equally likely the ratio of those values is the probability. Now assume $p_2$ and $p_3$ are the probabilities you pick two  black balls or two brown balls respectively. Then similarly
$$p_2=\frac {\binom{b}{2}}{\binom {a+b+c}{2}}$$
$$p_3=\frac {\binom{c}{2}}{\binom {a+b+c}{2}}$$
This should be enough to get you going.